# Duplicate and number rows "n" amount of times using Excel VBA

Tags: vba

I wrote some VBA code to prompt how many times to duplicate the rows.  I now want to add a feature to number in sequence the rows in column L.

```
Sub InsertRows()
    Dim I As Long, J As Integer, x As Integer, N As Long

    N = InputBox("type the number of rows to be inserted")

    For I = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
'        MsgBox Range("A1").Value & vbNewLine & J
        x = N
            For J = 1 To N - 1
                Rows(I + J).Insert xlDown
                Rows(I).Copy
                Rows(I + J).PasteSpecial
                Range("L" & J).Value = J
            Next
    Next
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

For example, if I type "3" in the message box, the rows will copy 3 times for each original item but the values in column L will not sequentially number 1-3 correctly.  what is going wrong here?

The result comes out like this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ0u3.png)

Comment: It has to do with your nested loop - why do you need two loops here? Couldn't you just indicate what line you're inserting rows at then number them from there?

Comment: `Range("L" & (J+i)).Value = J`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop logic 101... you have multiple problems here.

First, in your example of 3, `"rows to be inserted"` is not actually 3.  Since you use N-1, you are only inserting 2 rows.  Thus your J count is off.

Plus, `Range("L" & J).Value` is only ever changing rows 1 and 2.  And since you are doing everything from the botom up, it never sets anything to original row 3.  It only ever sets `2` to original row 2.  And original row 1 has a mix of `1` and `2`.  Thus you need to add your `I` offset to the `J` value in that equation.

Plus, why the assign to `x` when it's never used?

Hope that helps a little. :)